# Validating a textBox in simple calculator to only accept a number

Tags: c#

I am building a simple calculator( add + Multiply two numbers) using Windows Form Application

the code is working now but its when i try to validate it.

```
    private void txtBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double a, b, c; // Declearing Variables

        a = double.Parse(txtBox1.Text);
        b = double.Parse(txtBox2.Text);
        c = a + b;

        txtLbl.Text = c.ToString();
    }
```

I have tried this check:

```
        if (int.TryParse(txtBox.Text, out int tempNum1) == false)
            return;
```

and somthing like this:

```
    if ((int.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, out int num1) == false) && 
        (int.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, out int num2) == false))
      MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Number");

    return;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use `TryParse`, e.g.

```
private void txtBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (double.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, out double a) && 
        double.TryParse(txtBox2.Text, out double b))
      txtLbl.Text = (a + b).ToString(); // if both TextBoxes have valid values
    else { 
      // At least one TextBox has invalid Text
      txtLbl.Text = "???";  
    } 
}
```

If you want to help user in *error correction* we can name the invalid argument and put a keyboard focus on it:

```
private void txtBtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (double.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, out double a)) {
        if (double.TryParse(txtBox2.Text, out double b))   
            txtLbl.Text = (a + b).ToString(); 
        else {
            if (txtBox2.CanFocus)
                txtBox2.Focus();

            MessageBox("Mot a Valid 'B' Number");
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (txtBox1.CanFocus)
            txtBox1.Focus();

        MessageBox("Mot a Valid 'A' Number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to avoid doing any manual validation is to swap your text box for a `NumericUpDown` component, it does all the validation for you and works the same as a textbox.

---

Or you could use regex.

```
string compare = "1234";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d$");

if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
{ 
//It is only numbers
}
```